# VBA code copying forrmula pattern down a column

Tags: excel, vba

Please help with VBA code .I have formula in excel sheet in cell F6 want to copy same formula down that same F column after every 14th row the last formula will be inserted in in cell F2533 .Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Is the next cell to be filled **F20** pr **F21**??

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should get you close:

```
Sub copyformuladown14()
    copyRange As Range

    'Set range variable to F6 on sheet1
    Set copyRange = Sheet1.Range("F6")


    'Starting at row 20, loop every 14 rows and paste
    'you have to monkey with number "20"
    For i = 20 To 2533 Step 14
        copyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("F6").Offset(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: THanks JNevill am getting complie error message "statement invalid outside type block " when I paste the code

Comment: I'm not sure on that one. The sub works fine on my side. Are you on a mac by chance?